# What are the config for NewRelic ASP.NET Core appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, newrelic

The settings of referenced here was introduced as

> Here are instructions for enabling the agent for .NET Framework and.NET Core.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/installation/install-net-agent-windows/#app-config

It shows the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NewRelic.AgentEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="DataServices" />
  </appSettings>
```

But for ASP.NET Core, you don't use XML configuration, you use appsettings.json:

- What are the configuration for ASP.NET Core?
- Can the configuration be added to the `Configuration` of `Azure Web App Service` rather than in the local appsettings.json ? And if so, what are the keys?

Answer (score 0):

In the doc page you provide, it is explained how to set it up in dotnet core.

You don't need to add anything to the appsettings file; just set an environment variable. Beware that it must be set only in the project's scope or all dotnet core applications running on the host will be monitored.

```
CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
```

They provide a helpful link to a page with even more details: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/setting-net-core-agent-environment-variables-per-process/157750

In addition to the methods they mention, you could also put the variable in a .env file and load it, for example as explained here https://dusted.codes/dotenv-in-dotnet